# Append text in a given section in a word document using PHP

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I have a word document with various sections. 

I need to append some more text in a particular section of word document using PHP.

After searching in google, came across phpoffice/phpword.

Using that I am able to write a new word document.

Not getting how to insert text in a given section.

Looks there is template processing in phpoffice.

Using template processing is it possible to insert text in a given section.

Is there any such example ?

Or is there any other good open source (php based) available, that provides easy apis to append text in a particular section.

Using below code, I can generate a new word document in phpoffice.

```
$filename = "sample";
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars("Some text"));
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('./doc/' . $filename . '.docx');
```

However I want to write section wise (with section numbers like 1.1 or 1.2).
At a later stage need to append some more text to a particular section.

If it can be done using phpoffice, that will be my most preferred approach.

Comment: show us some code! show us what you've done so far - or what does not work! *`giv-me-teh-code`*-questions are usually to get deleted...

Comment: I am going to edit my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, just Word, but in terms of Word your requirement isn't clear. In Word a SECTION is a very particular object; it's used to provide different headers/footers, page size/orientation, newspaper columns in a document. I  get the impression that's not what you mean? It seems to me what you want is a few levels of numbered headings - at least to begin with? And at a later point you want to add content to these headings? How much later?

Comment: Under a numbered heading(say 1.0 Introduction), there will be some text, say 2 paragraphs. I want a insert a new paragraph in that section.